# choosing product for simulating a mifare classic tag

Tags: nfc, rfid, mifare

I'm looking for a programmable product that allows me to simulate a dynamically programmable mifare classic tag.
I known that AMS, NXP and ST products cannot chieve this.
RyscCorp products are banned in my country.

Can anyone tell me if there is a verified, existing product that allows me to simulate a mifare classic tag?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Mifare Classic tags a little bit tricky to emulate because they use a stream cipher on framing level which means that common NFC Readerchips or dynamic tags can not be used because they doing the frame handling in hardware which can not bypassed. Further Mifare Classic cipher(crypto1) is NXP property which means that basically only NXP products have Mifare Classic support (there are some exceptions) What is possible that you do your coding/decoding by your own with a Reader chip which allows you. As far as I know TI has the TRF7970 [link](http://www.ti.com/product/TRF7970A) which you can put in transparent mode which means you can code/decode the signal by your own including crypto1 cipher. There are some publication about this cipher because it is broken some years ago.
As Far as I know there is no existing "ready to use" product on the market which allows you to emulate a Mifare Classic tag.